# Weird error: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 75 near 'submit': Error: 'submit' is not defined

Tags: orm, symfony, doctrine-orm, repository

My controller is:

```
  /**
   * @Route("/product/submit", name="product_submit") 
   * @Template("GaorenVendorsBundle:Product:index.html.twig")
   */
  public function submitAction()
  {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $uid = $this->getUser()->getId();
        $em->getRepository( 'GaorenVendorsBundle:Product' )->updateStatus( $uid, Product::STATUS_FREE, Product::STATUS_PENDING );

        return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl( 'product' ) );
  }
```

and my repo is:

```
class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{

  public function updateStatus($uid, $status, $setter)
  {
        $st = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository( 'GaorenVendorsBundle:Product' )
              ->createQueryBuilder( 'p' )
              ->update( 'GaorenVendorsBundle:Product', 'p' )
              ->set( 'p.status', ':setter' )
              ->where( 'p.status= :status AND p.user= :user' )
              ->setParameters( array(
                      'user' => $uid,
                      'status' => $status,
                      'setter' => $setter
              ) )
              ->getQuery()
              ->execute()

        return $st;
  }
```

twig:

```
    <a class="btn btn-large btn-primary " href="{{ path('product_submit') }}">
        <i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i>
        {{ 'create a new entry'|trans }}
    </a>
```

When requesting the "submit" action it prompts me:

```
[Semantical Error] line 0, col 75 near 'submit': Error: 'submit' is not defined.
```

"submit" has nothing to do with the Doctrine ORM query, why does it appear in the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could it be that you have a route matching something like `/product/{id}` above that one?

This would match your `/product/submit` route and think of `$id` as the string `"submit"`. The first matching route wins in Symfony. Then if you try to retrieve a Product object from this id, such an error could be thrown.

The solution is to move your submit action above the action handling the `/product/{id}` route.

Comment: I'd like to, but not enough reputation, sry... :(